# Que ou quoi + infinitif

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-interrogatifs, niveau-de-langue

Je m'interroge sur ces deux tournures de phrase :

> Pouvez-vous m'indiquer **que** répondre ?
>
> Pouvez-vous m'indiquer **quoi** répondre ?

Sont-elles toutes les deux correctes ? Ont-elles le même niveau de langue ?

Answer (score 2):

Ici je recommande d'utiliser "*quoi*".

Ça vaut pour le formel et informel.

Il semble qu'il existe des formulations très soutenues qui utilisent "*que*", par exemple : "*je ne sais que dire*". En revanche, elles restent assez marginales, et étant donné que même des francophones ont du mal à se mettre d'accord sur leur existence, je recommande de ne pas les utiliser. "*Pouvez-vous m'indiquer quoi répondre ?*" convient très bien pour un contexte formel.

On peut aussi rencontrer une construction très similaire, assez soutenue :

> **Que** faire ?
>
> **Que** dire de plus ?

Dans ce cas-là il faut utiliser "*que*". La construction en elle-même est soutenue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50400/discussion-on-answer-by-teleporting-goat-que-ou-quoi-infinitif).

Answer (score -1):

Les deux formes sont correctes.

"Pouvez-vous me dire quoi répondre" est beaucoup plus courant.

Mais:

"Pouvez-me dire que faire/que dire/que répondre", est d'un niveau registre de langue (qui me semble) plus soutenu, et parfaitement correct.

On peut trouver cette forme dans des poésies par exemple. (Je rajoute dès que je retrouve)

"Pouvez-vous me dire que faire" est d'un registre de langue plus élevé (je pense) que:
"Pouvez-vous me dire quoi faire".

Tout dépend du contexte !

Source:

Livre: "études de syntaxe interrogative du français: Quoi, combien et le complémenteur" de Hans-Georg Obenauer.

Extrait:

> La construction n'est pas libre, "que" doit immédiatement suivre savoir"
>
> Ex: Je ne sais pas que faire.
>   Je ne sais plus du tout que faire.
>   Je ne sais pas quoi faire.
>   Je ne sais plus du tout quoi faire.

**Ne (pas) savoir que faire**: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_savoir_que_faire

construit sur le même modèle que "**ne pas savoir que répondre**".

EDIT: visiblement "quoi faire" passe beaucoup mieux que "que faire" auprès de la majorité.

Comment: Tous les exemples que vous donnez sont des propositions interrogatives indirectes dans des phrases à la forme **affirmative**. "Que" peut effectivement être employé dans ce cas-là (cf CNTRL II. A. 2. b) En revanche, la question de SamuelTb porte sur des formes **interrogatives**, donc il semble que ça ne marche pas.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de réelle différence grammaticale entre: "Je lui indique que répondre" et "Peux-tu m'indiquer que répondre". Je ferai encore des recherches (si j'en trouve le courage). Mais l'usage de "que" est plus vaste que ce qu'en dit le CNTL, ça me semble certain, parce qu'il n'a pas vocation à ça.