# Que d’autre pourrais-je faire ? / Que pourrais-je faire d’autre ?

Tags: constructions

Bonjour,

> Que **d’autre** pourrais-je faire ?
>
> Que pourrais-je faire **d’autre** ?

D'après vous, quelle phrase est plus belle ?

Comment: Seule la deuxième est grammaticalement correcte, en tout cas.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais la deuxième :

> *Que pourrais-je faire d'autre ?*

La première n'utilise pas le pronom attendu<sup>1</sup>. Ce qui se dit et s'écrit :

> ***Quoi** d'autre pourrais-je faire ?*

Ces deux formes, utilisant des inversions, sont soutenues. On pourrait les lire dans un roman mais peu de chance de les entendre prononcer spontanément.

À l'oral, on entendra plutôt :

> *Qu'est-ce que je pourrais faire d'autre ?*

ou plus relâché :

> *Je pourrais faire quoi d'autre ?*

Voir aussi: [Que ou quoi + infinitif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23582/que-ou-quoi-infinitif)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Le fait d'avoir deux pronoms interrogatifs,* quoi *et* que, *pour un même sémantisme, complexifie les données. L'un épouse les caractéristiques des pronoms conjoints alors que l'autre suit les propriétés des pronoms disjoints. De même que les pronoms conjoints,* que *doit se trouver juxtaposé au verbe conjugué et ne peut s'en trouver séparé que par un autre élément clitique, comme la négation* ne.

Florence Lefeuvre, *[Analyse grammaticale et sur corpus de l’expression c’est
quoi (?)](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01519591/document)*, 2015</sub>

Comment: Merci, je me demande pourquoi _**Que d’autre** pourrais-je faire ?_ n'est pas possible, car il s'agit seulement, à moin avis, de déplacer _d'autre_ dans ma phrase. La première phrase aurait dû être aussi correcte, non ?

Comment: Non, dans une interrogative, *que* et *quoi* peuvent être en concurrence devant un verbe (*que dire ?* ou *quoi dire ?* sont possibles, le premier est plus soutenu) mais de *que d'autre* n'est pas grammatical.

Comment: [...] mais *que d'autre* n'est pas [...] (il y avait un "de" en trop...)

Comment: Oui, merci, je l'ai compris.